# Regex to match as many times as possible, but within constraints

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Here's my string:

`"ab1 ab-1 f-12 g-12 ffff-123 456"`

I'd like to pick out things that have:

- Up to 2 letters
- An optional hyphen
- Up to 2 numbers
- **Valid**: ab1, ab-1, f-12, g-12
- **Not Valid**: ffff-123, 456

So I created the regex:

`[\w{1,2}]-?\d{1,2}`

But it returns too many things:

```
>>> re.findall('[\w{1,2}]-?\d{1,2}', "ab1 ab-1 f-12 g-12 ffff-123 456")
['b1', 'b-1', 'f-12', 'g-12', 'f-12', '456']
```

The problems:

1. `[\w{1,2}]` needs to be isolated from `-?`.....I think they are being stuck together
2. `[\w{1,2}]` is getting the smallest possible match e.g. `b-1` from `ab-1`, when it should get the largest possible match up to 2 characters, `ab-1`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to match the edge cases, i.e. tokens like "ab-" or "-45", or even "-"? The question as currently posted leaves this out for interpretation. If you do, this will break the regexes relying on word boundary anchors (\b) proposed by Barmar and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RE should be:

```
[a-z]{1,2}-?\d{1,2}
```

The expression `[\w{1,2}]` means any single character that's either a word character, `{`, `1`, `,`, `2`, or `}`.

Note that in your string this will match `ff-12`, since this part of `ffff-123` matches the expression. If you don't want this to happen you need to add `\b` around the expression, so that it only matches at word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks! this is great, but adding the \b breaks it. Am I doing something wrong here? \b[a-z]{1,2}-?\d{1,2}

Comment: Make sure you use raw strings, i.e. `r'\b[a-z]{1,2}-?\d{1,2}'` so that the backslash won't be eaten by the string parser.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should look like that:

```
\b[a-z]{1,2}-?[\d]{1,2}\b
```

It's because `\w` matches all alpha-**numeric** symbols including all the digits you don't want to find in your string.

Also there should be `\b` on the boundaries of RE because of this example: `ffff-123`.

RE without `\b` would match the part of this example but it shouldn't so we add `\b` to make it search only at the word's boundary

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is perfect but Barmar got there first, so I have to give him the upvote :)

Comment: No problem :) (At least I've got my 10 reputation points for this)